# Como alinha 2 resultado while por linha

Tags: php, css

Como posso fazer que as divs contidas no loop, listem 2 por linha ao invés de listar uma em baixa da outra

Exemplo a baxco

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM aparelhos  ";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
$nome = $row['nome'];
<div><?echo $nome?></div>
}

//como normalmente e visualizado
Fulano de Tal
Maria Fulana
Home Simpson
Lisa Simpson

//como queria que visualiza-se
Fulano de Tal             Maria Fulana
Homer Simpson             Lisa Simpson
....                      ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é uma questão de formatação da página. Estilo! Então você deve realmente usar [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp).

Você pode fazer suas [`<div></div>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) ficarem lado a lado:

```css
div{
  width: 49%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}
```

Se você não quiser ocupar a largura de [`<body></body>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp) completamente, defina um elemento-pai `DIV` fora do [loop](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) (laço de repetição) [`while`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) e defina a largura máxima que deseja ocupar com a impressão dos dados lado a lado pelo PHP.

Referência para o atributo `float` [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float).

Veja o CSS em ação: [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/s1p4pjkk/19/)